# WlanApi: fetch MacAddress of Wireless signal without connecting

Tags: c++, mac-address, wlanapi

Using WlanApi.lib, I am able to get the Listof Available signal details using WlanGetAvailableNetworkList function[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In order to get the Mac Address, Channel of each available signal, I need to use WlanQueryInterface function. This function works only on the current connected network. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms706749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is there any option to fetch the MacAddress and channel for each and every available Wireless signal with out connecting.

can anyone help me to find the way to extract network adapter supported types a/b/g/n??

Answer (score 0):

Use [WlanGetNetworkBssList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can either ask for `MACID` of a specific network or the entire list.  Thanks for asking this question, because I could not figure out how to determine which network I was connected to.  I'll need to try WlanQueryInterface.